# TextInput in Second Tab not shifting up when keyboard pops up react-navigation createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I used createMaterialTopTabNavigator to create a TopTabNavigator. This tab navigator has two pages each page has a few TextInput fields inside. Both tabs use the same component but their behaviour is different in Android. When the keyboard pops up after a TextInput focus, the screen shifts up in the first tab but in the second tab the screen remains still and keyboard hides the TextInput. I already changed the activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml to   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but this feature is not working for the second tab.

Here is the simplified code sample:

```
const Test = props => {
 return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
     <TextInput placeholder="test 1" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 2" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 1" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 2" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 1" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 2" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 1" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 2" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 1" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 2" />
     <TextInput placeholder="test 1333" />
   </View>
 );
};
const TopTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
 {
  Tab1: { screen: Test },
  Tab2: { screen: Test }
 }
);
export default createAppContainer(TopTabNavigator);
```